# AWS CloudFront responses 307 Temporary Redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

An IoT device is sending data:

- by POST method
- by HTTP (not HTTPS)
- and doesn't follow redirects

I created an end-point on AWS API GateWay and I created an AWS CloudFront and configured like this:

- **Origin Domain Name:** myAPIgw.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
- **Origin Protocol Policy:** HTTPS Only
- **Viewer Protocol Policy:** Redirected HTTP to HTTPS
- **Allowed HTTP Methods:** GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
- **Cache Policy:** Managed-CachingDisabled

When I send request by Postman (auto follow redirect turned off) these are responses:

`POST https://myAPIgw.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com` --> 200 Success

`POST https://Mycloudfront.cloudfront.net`  --> 200 Success

`POST http://Mycloudfront.cloudfront.net`  -->  307 Temporary Redirect

Any idea to get 200 by HTTP ?

Comment: Set viewer protocol to HTTP? I'm not sure what do you aim to achieve? You want to use only HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @Marcin I want to send data by http but API Gateway only works by https so I sent data to cloud front then cloudFront ridirects http to https then send it to Api Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use HTTP, then you should set:

```
Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTP and HTTPS
```

and

```
Origin Protocol Policy: HTTPS Only
```

This way you can query the CloudFront endpoint either using HTTP or HTTPS, and no redirection is required from HTTP to HTTPS.